# 3D cursor to geometry generated by a modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode, 3d-cursor

I need to set the 3D cursor on a point generated by an array. I tried with "Adjust edit cage to modifier result" and "Display modifier in edit mode", but when I select the point with the little circle, the 3D cursor sets to the point on the original object (like in the image).

How can I do it **without applying the modifier**? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You could turn on snap during transform, add an empty, move the empty to the desired vertex, then snap to cursor to the empty. Honestly I'd probably just duplicate the object and apply the modifier.

Comment: Thank you! It's easy with a duplicate. Now I can keep modeling. How can I mark your answer as correct or close the thread or something?